# How to open a document located on a WebDAV server from a Java applet on MAC OS X?

Tags: macos, applet, webdav, mount, opendocument

I need to open a document for editing with associated application on MAC OS X from Java applet. The document is located on a WebDAV server.

What command should I use to open a document?
Is it necessary to mount a volume first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to open a document for editing with associated application..

`Desktop.getDesktop().edit(File)`

Comment: Ok, to mount a WebDAV I need to run mount_webdav command. And than to use Desktop.edit()